# How to extract last line of text in Python (excluding new lines)?

Tags: python, extract

Textfile:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
\n
\n
```

I know `lines[-1]` gets you the last line, but I want to disregard any new lines and get the last line of text (6 in this case).

Comment: Does your file contain exactly __two__ newlines?

Comment: No, i want to disregard any number of new lines

Answer (score 1):

The best approach regarding memory is to exhaust the file. Something like this:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
  last = None
  for line in (line for line in f if line.rstrip('\n')):
    last = line

print last
```

It can be done more elegantly though. A slightly different approach:

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
  last = None
  for last in (line for line in f if line.rstrip('\n')):
    pass

print last
```

Comment: This is a `O(n)` solution. Can we optimize it further?

Comment: Maybe you can treat the file as binary, and try to get a chunk from the end of the file, see if it contains a linebreak, etc. It is still O(n) but average case would be better

Answer (score 0):

For a small file you can just read all of the lines, discarding any empty ones. Notice that I've used an inner generator to strip the lines before excluding them in the outer one.

```
with open(textfile) as fp:
    last_line = [l2 for l2 in (l1.strip() for l1 in fp) if l2][-1]
```

Comment: This has horrible space efficiency. That list could grow to be too large to fit into main memory

Comment: @inspectorG4dget - OP mentioned 6 lines and I qualified this answer as suitable for small files. A more complicated solution where, for instance, the tail is read and scanned for the last line (with a fallback to read more) is simply not called for with small files.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file') as f:
    print([i for i in f.read().split('\n') if i != ''][-1])
```

This is just an edit to Avinash Raj's answer (but since I'm a new account, I can't comment on it). This will preserve any None values in your data (i.e. if the data in your last line is "None" it will work, though depending on your input this may not be an issue).

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('path/to/file') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        if not line.strip('\n'):
            continue
        answer = line
    print(answer)
```

This will print `6` with a newline at the end. You can decide how to strip that. Following are some options:

- `answer.rstrip('\n')` removes trailing newlines
- `answer.rstrip()` removes trailing whitespaces
- `answer.strip()` removes any surrounding whitespaces

Answer (score -1):

```py
with open ('file.txt') as myfile:
  for num,line in enumerate(myfile):
    pass
print num
```